# How do you name the major sector of a circle?

Tags: geometry, terminology, circles

When it comes to arcs, you distinguish between minor arcs and major arcs by using either the two endpoints (for minor arcs) or the two endpoints plus an additional point on the arc for major arcs.

Both my textbook and the internet say that sectors are named with the two endpoints of the arc and the center of the circle, but this does not distinguish between major sectors and minor sectors. How do you name a major sector? Thanks!

Comment: The "additional point" strategy applies.

Comment: Can you give an example? Where does the additional point go relative to the others? Let's a A and B and the endpoints, P is the center, and C is the additional point. Would it be sector APCB, or what?

Comment: The notation is simply "center + arc" (or "arc + center"). If it takes three points to name the arc, then it takes four points to name the sector. Put the points in the order you traverse the boundary of the figure, just as you would a polygon ... but it's good practice to have the distinguished center point either first or last. So, for your example, I would write $PACB$ or $ACBP$ (and/or clockwise-vs-counterclockwise variants).